Dockerignore is not ignoring a specific folder
I have a Dockerfile like this, in ./lang-runner:
FROM debian:12

COPY . .

And a .dockerignore in . like this:
postgres-data

Postgres data looks like this:
drwx------ 19       999 root       4096 Oct 12 19:34 postgres-data

It's owned by root since it's created by another container. I can't easily change it.
I run the container like this:
docker build -f lang-runner/Dockerfile .

But I get this error:
$ docker build -f lang-runner/Dockerfile .

[+] Building 16.7s (7/15)                                                                                                                                                     
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 910B                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => ERROR [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring context: 73B                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/debian:12                                                                                                             0.0s
 => ERROR [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                  0.2s
 => => transferring context: 450.00kB                                                                                                                                    0.2s
 => [stage-1 1/4] FROM docker.io/library/debian:12bullseye@sha256:8006c4ffd4af7e8de914e921f1dc26d2a0eb8ce95ffd7e5455bb05e84b673555                                   0.0s
------
 > [internal] load .dockerignore:
------
------
 > [internal] load build context:
------
error from sender: open postgres-data: permission denied

Why is it trying to open postgres-data even though it's in the .dockerignore. How do I get my container to build without changing the permissions of the postgres folder?
I'm on WSL with windows docker desktop if it matters.

I can't reproduce your issue. When I try, it works as expected. Is your postgres-data directory in the root of the context or is it in the lang-runner directory?

@HansKilian it's in the root folder of the context

It might be a WSL issue. I tried on Ubuntu and it worked there.
